# wordpress ajax form submission is not working?

Tags: ajax, database, wordpress

Here is the code..I think action i ajax not working and getting 403 error! using Wamp and running Wordpress on it

js code
    jQuery('#InsertionForm').submit(

```
function (){
var x = jQuery('#nm').val();
var y = jQuery('#em').val();

jQuery.ajax({
type:"POST",

url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",

data: { 
        action: 'get_my_option',
        namo: x, 
        emao: y
    },

success:function(){
    alert("working");
}
});

return false;

});
```

main plugin code ..please can anyone tell me ...the given bellow code is in right sequence or not?

```
    <?php

/*

Plugin Name: lucky

*/


//adding script files in HTML

wp_enqueue_script('myscript', plugins_url('myscript.js', __FILE__), 

array('jquery'), '', true);

wp_localize_script( 'myscript', 'my_ajax_object',

            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );


function get_my_option()

{

    //do something

   alert("this is a function action: in ajax");

}

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_option", "get_my_option");

add_action("wp_ajax_get_my_option", "get_my_option");



    #Shortcode function.........................................

function html_form_code() {

    global $wpdb;

    # Input form fields.....

    echo '<form method="post" id="InsertionForm">';

    echo '<h3>Insertion Form</h3>';

    echo '<p>Your Name (required) <br/>';

    echo '<input id="nm" type="text" name="namel" value="" size="40" />';

    echo '</p>';

    echo '<p>';

    echo 'Your Email (required) <br/>';

    echo '<input id="em" type="email" name="emaill" value="" size="40" />';

    echo '</p>';

    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Send"> ';

    echo '</form>';
}

function my_ajax() {

    $nom = $_POST['namo'];

    $emo = $_POST['emao'];

    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb -> insert( 'lucky_wpdb', array('namel' => $nom, 'emaill' => $emo) 

);

echo 'Submitted';

}



    //Shortcode working here....

add_shortcode( 'sitepoint_contact_form', 'html_form_code' );

?>
```

Comment: You want submit form in admin panel or front-end?

Comment: @Quỳnh Nguyễn it's front-end

Comment: Okay let show me HTML content of this form

Comment: I'm building a plugin that can save form data in database using ajax...

Comment: echo '<form method="post" id="InsertionForm">';
 
 echo '<h3>Insertion Form</h3>';
 
 echo '<p>Your Name (required) <br/>';
 
 echo '<input id="nm" type="text" name="namel" value="" size="40" />';
 
 echo '</p>';
 
 echo '<p>';
 
 echo 'Your Email (required) <br/>';
 
 echo '<input id="em" type="email" name="emaill" value="" size="40" />';
 
 echo '</p>';
 
 echo '<p><input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Send"> ';
 
 echo '</form>';

Comment: check your data field, it should be--> data : { 
        action: 'get_my_option',
        namo: x, 
        emao: y
    }

Comment: @abhirathore2006 ...still same problem...

Comment: You could look at the [documentation here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/2335/ajax/9008/ajax-with-ajax-and-wordpress-nonce#t=201607230823023341478) about AJAX calls.

Comment: You are using php inside js file, that is wrong replace `url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",` with `url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url` .

Comment: @Shravan Shrama it doesn't matter...I'm getting right query string  but not able to insert in database...console log is giving 403 error: you are not permitted to access wordpress/ on this server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for helping me...But I have solved the issue..
here is the code for answer seekers......It works....

Here is the main php file of plugin...I was created..

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: lucky
Plugin URI: 
Description: 
Version: 
Author: 
Author URI: 
License: 
License URI: 
*/


    #Ajax action function.......
function get_my_option() {  

    $nom = $_POST['namo'];
    $emo = $_POST['emao'];

    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb -> insert( 'lucky_wpdb', array('namel' => $nom, 'emaill' => $emo) );
    echo 'Submitted';

}


    #Shortcode function.........................................
function html_form_code() {

    # Input form fields.....
    echo '<form method="post" id="InsertionForm">';

    echo '<h3>Insertion Form</h3>';

    echo '<p>Your Name (required) <br/>';

    echo '<input id="nm" type="text" name="namel" value="" size="40" />';

    echo '</p>';

    echo '<p>';

    echo 'Your Email (required) <br/>';

    echo '<input id="em" type="email" name="emaill" value="" size="40" />';

    echo '</p>';

    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Send"> ';

    echo '</form>';

}

//adding script files....

wp_enqueue_script('myscript', plugins_url('myscript.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '', true); // ajax script file...

wp_localize_script( 'myscript', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); //including admin-ajax.php in website html

    //Shortcode working here....
add_shortcode( 'sitepoint_contact_form', 'html_form_code' );

?>
```

myscript.js code...

```
// AJAX FORM SUBMITION CODE......


jQuery('#InsertionForm').submit(

function ajaxSubmit(){

var x = jQuery('#nm').val();
var y = jQuery('#em').val();

jQuery.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
data: { 
        'action': 'get_my_option', //action calling to insert data in wordpress db...
        'namo': x, 
        'emao': y
    },
success:function($data){
    alert($data);

}
});

return false;

})
```

Put this code in functions.php of your selected theme...

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
add_action("wp_ajax_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
```

Answer (score 0):

To make ajax action work you need to defined the separate actions for logged in and not-logged in users.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

where `wp_ajax_nopriv_` means for not logged in user and `wp_ajax_` means logged in user also `my_action` is your actual action. they can call to send action method or different depending on your requirements

Comment: when i click on submit button it gives error 403. You don't have permission to access /wordpress/< on this server. but query string is having all variables and values in it...

Comment: can you check at which page this is sending data to ?  then try to open the same page through browser. you will know whats going on there

Comment: I just did that.. the output in html on that page is forbidden....you can't access this page from the server(wamp)

Comment: alert () on server really ? use --> echo "hello world" also if you open      /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php you will get 0 in browser , if so then your configuration is ok otherwise it is messed up

Comment: I'think you're right...it doesn't show 0....it shows forbidden permission not granted....nothing else....

Comment: check your .htaccess file and try to find why its forbidden

Comment: .htaccess if you are talking about wamp file than...it's empty

Comment: see if there is any .htaccess in wordpress root directory also check in wordpress/wp-admin directory

Answer (score 0):

Why is there `alert` in your action method `get_my_option`?

And to work with ajax in WP you should echo and them die;

try this

```
function get_my_option()

{    
    //do something

   echo "this is a function action: in ajax";
   die();    
}
```